# Fixed Element in Swiper Slide relative to Slide

Tags: html, css, swiper.js

I´m trying to have two images in one slide where I want the second one to work as a lightbox.

But I can´t get the div of the second image to be fixed. It´s always relative to the swiper slide, but I want it to be fixed over the whole screen.

Here´s a very basic example of the two images in a slide and the fixed positioning:

```
https://codepen.io/webkonditorei/pen/XWEbRgm
```

Here´s the code of the Codepen:

```
<div class="swiper-container swiper1">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg"> <div id="fix"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg"></div></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p>Slide 2</p></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p>Slide 3</p></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p>Slide 4</p></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p>Slide 5</p></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p>Slide 6</p></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p>Slide 7</p></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p>Slide 8</p></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p>Slide 9</p></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><p>Slide 10</p></div>
          
        </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination1"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-prev1"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-next1"></div>
    </div>

<style>
body {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.sliderContainer {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next {
  position: absolute;
}

p {
  cursor: pointer;
}


#fix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
</style>


<script>

<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
var swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper1', {
   slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 10,
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination1',
    paginationClickable: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next1',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev1',
  },
});

</script>
```